# An example of a sum of meromorphic functions that is not meromorphic itself

Tags: complex-analysis, meromorphic-functions

Suppose we have two meromorphic functions $f$ and $g$. Then what is an example of such functions where then $f+g$ is not meromorphic?

Answer (score 1):

No. Actually, the meromorphic functions from an open subset $D$ of $\mathbb C$ into $\mathbb C$ form a field; it particular, they are closed under addition.